# Questions about my Database MySQL and Android Studio

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, android-studio

I want to make an app that show list of quotes to the user, and each user can favorites the quotes they like, so that the user can see all of the favorites quotes that the user favorited.

I want to make the app on Android Studio and using MySQL, not SQLite.

So if I want each user to have their own favorites list, then I must make a user table right? for login?

Is this table right?

**Table User**

- user_id (Integer,Primary Key, Not null, Auto Increment)
- email(Text or varchar?? , Not Null)
- Password(Text or varchar??, Not Null)

**Table QuoteList**

- quote_id (Integer, Primary key, Not Null, Auto Increment)
- quotes (text, Not Null)
- author (varchar(30), Not Null)
- genre (I want it to have multivalue, like : motivational,love)

**My Questions is:**

1. What's the correct type for email,password, and genre?
2. Where do I put the Favorite Column, the Table User or Table QuoteList?
3. The Favorite column should be boolean with default 0 right?

**EDIT POST**

So I will have to make three tables:

1. User Table
2. QuoteList Table
3. UserFavourite Table

The User Favourite Table have two foreign keys, that is:

1. user_id
2. quote_id

and so, here is the example of populated userFavourite Table

```
user_id     quote_id

  1           2    
  1           3    
  1           4    
  2           4    
  2           6
```

Is it like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Email, password and genre can be varchar.
Since you want the members to choose their favorite quotes, you need to create a relationship between User and QuoteList table.

You can create another table

UserFavorite
user_id 
quote_id

user_id and quote_id comes from the other two tables. This way you know which user favorites which quote. user_id comes from the logged in user and quote_id comes from any quote from the list of quotes.

Comment: Can you look at my Edited Post? So that i can ask you more

Comment: yes, that's it. Now when you need to retrieve the list of favorites for a particular user, just fetch all the the posts where user_id in UserFavorite is == current logged in user id. This will give you a list of quote_id which you can find from your QuoteList table.

Comment: And i want to ask more, if the user favorite a quote, then unfavorited it, how can i make that disappear from the table? sorry for noob questions

Comment: When they hit unfavorite from within the app you should have the logged in loggesinuserID and postID, you can use those 2 parameters...send it to AsyncTask to make a call to your PHP. The PHP file will take two of those parameters and make SQL call like "delete from UserFavorite where user_id = loggedinuserID and post_id = postID"

Comment: I see, Thank you so much !! i will try it now :))

Comment: It's okay. I'm a noob too but i worked with something similar before :P